# Decreasing hard drive sync time with Unison

Tags: rsync, unison

I'm using Unison to synchronize my music collection to a few different sources, namely a couple computers over SSH and a hard drive.

One thing I've noticed is that SSH updates are incredibly *fast* in comparison to hard drive syncs, possibly because `rsync` (or whatever's running under the hood) is only moving what's changed. Add that to the fact that I can run multiple SSH copy actions at once and copying to a local USB hard drive is left in the dust, as it only copies one file at a time and overwrites the entire file every time.

When changing the encoding of ID3v1 tags (for compatibility tests), my entire ~5000 file music library changes needs to be backed up to the other computers and hard drive.

Is there any way for me to:

1. increase the number of simultaneous copies; and
2. only copying the parts of the files that have changed?

Here's my Unison profile:

```
# Unison preferences
batch = false
confirmbigdel = true
copymax = 10
logfile = .unison/unison-music.log
maxthreads = 30
perms = 0
sortbysize = true

root = /home/me/Music
root = /media/truecrypt1/media/music
```

Comment: Why don't you also use rsync for the hard drive? And are you using `unison` or `rsync`, or plain scp? It's really hare to tell from your post/question.

Comment: I'm using Unison and assuming that under the hood, it uses `rsync` to move files around.

Comment: Unison doesn't use `rsync` at all. (See the [papers](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/papers/index.shtml#File%20Synchronization) linked on the main site.)

Comment: that conflicts with their tutorial here: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html see 'copyprog xxx' where it states 'The default setting invokes rsync with appropriate options—most users should not need to change it.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
copythreshold = 1024
```

Then unison changes files bigger than 1Mb in place using `rsync` instead of completely re-transferring.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `fastcheck` option is turned on (it should be by default if both sides are unix systems). By default, Unison looks at the whole contents of every file on each side. This is safer: it guarantees that after Unison has run, the contents are the same on both sides. It is also faster if the modification time of a file may change for spurious reasons. For large files, this can be slow. With the `fastcheck` option, Unison will consider a file to be unchanged if its size and modification has not changed (rsync does this optimization by default).

Answer (score 0):

Look at `man rsync` and search for the `whole file` option. `--no-whole-file` is possibly what you are looking for. I guess unison has a similar option.